# How can I "Merge Visible" to a layer in a Photoshop script?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

The `activeDocument.mergeVisibleLayers();` command simply flattens the image to the Background layer.

I am looking for a way to merge all layers to a new layer which stays on top of all other layers, like the Layer->Merge Visible (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) Photoshop command.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution but it worked for me:

```
// Copy all visible layers to clipboard (true = merged)
activeDocument.activeLayer.copy(true);
// then paste them (creates a new layer)
activeDocument.paste();
```

Comment: this is not working as it selects the active layer. it will not select ALL layers

Answer (score 0):

[The answer by George](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45771755/3151675) does not work well with tranparent images (it crops the transparency and aligns the pasted image to the middle). Here is a script that simply **executes the Merge Visible command**, found with [the Scripting Listener plug-in](http://blogs.adobe.com/crawlspace/2006/05/installing_and_1.html):

```
var idMrgV = charIDToTypeID("MrgV");
executeAction(idMrgV, undefined, DialogModes.NO);
```